# Unexplained types don't match error

Tags: java, swing, hashmap

I built a HashMap in a class like so:

```
 public static HashMap<String, String> makeMap(String file) {
  HashMap wordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  try {
     Scanner dictionFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

     while(dictionFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] values = new String[2];
        values = dictionFile.nextLine().split(",");
        wordMap.put(values[0], values[1]);
     }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("File not found!");
  } 
  return wordMap;
}
```

I then call my makeMao function as follows:

```
  HashMap dictionaryMap = Maintainance.makeMap("dictionary.txt");
  String button = e.getActionCommand();
  String homeUrl = "http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/";
  String glossUrl = "http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/go01.html";
  String searchedValue;
  String completeUrl;
  URL searchedUrl;
  String msgPart1 = "The word you are searching for cannot be found. ";
  String msgPart2 = "You are being rerouted to the glossary.";
  String message = msgPart1 + msgPart2;
  String title = "word Not Found";
  if (button == "Search") {
     String searchKey = textField.getText();
     searchedValue = dictionaryMap.get(searchKey);
```

I cannot figure out why it is giving me the error saying:incompatible types it is pointing at my searchKey variable inside of my searchedValue statement. required is String and found is Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (button == "Search")
```

In your above code its wrong , in Java String are compare as

```
if(button.equals("Search"))
```

[Referrence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

You should type-caste map

```
HashMap wordMap = new HashMap();
```

to

```
   Map<Object,Object> wordMap =new HashMap<Object,Object>();
```

Now in your code

```
     String searchKey = textField.getText();
     searchedValue = dictionaryMap.get(searchKey);
```

I think your dicionarymap is returning an Object but you are setting it to a String.You will need to convert an Object to String first.

Comment: are you suggesting using the toString() method? if so I tried to use it by using it by saying:
    searchedValue = dictionaryMap.get(searchKey).toString();
I do not know of another way to convert the returned object to a String.

Comment: Yes. But it would be a better idea if you had declared type for the map.

Comment: Ok, i finally got it to work using your advice. I appreciate the help!